# Multiselection on mouse drag is not working properly when a row is already selected

Tags: wpf, datagrid

In a datagrid, when a row is already selected and if you wish to select the consecutive rows by dragging it does not work in the below scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is focus. While the selection *is* in fact the row, remember that each cell is a visual object and can be `focus`ed. `DataGrid` has handlers behind the scenes that change the selection based on which cell currently has focus; for what you're doing, there's nothing wrong with that except when you want to use mouse drag for multi select. So you have to remove the focus from the clicked cell immediately after the first cell is clicked and the `DataGrid`'s selection has changed. What worked for me is changing the focus to the `DataGrid` itself.

In the XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridTopics" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="datagridTopic_SelectionChanged" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonDown="DataGridTopics_MouseLeftButtonDown" CurrentCellChanged="DataGrid_CurrentCellChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Topics" CanUserSort="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserReorder="False" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Text}" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void DataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dg = (DataGrid)sender;
    dg.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

with the focus on CurrentCellChanged you lose the keyboard arrow actions (and possibly more)

this solution keeps the keyboard :

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{   
    DataGrid.Focus();
    base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
}
```