# Issue with doubleclick on datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have the following on a datagrid in my C# code:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>  
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding CmdTransUnitFillerRowDblClick}" />  
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

It works for the most part except if user first selects the row (single click) and then tries double-clicking the row. In this situation the CmdTransUnitFillerRowDblClick code is never fired for processing.

So, how can I get the CmdTransUnitFillerRowDblClick to fire correctly on a double-click when the row is already selected?
Since someone may ask:

```
private void ExecutecmdTransUnitFillerRowDblClick(object parameter)  
{
    if (DgTransUnitFillerSelectedItem != null)
        TransUnitFillerDoubleClick(DgTransUnitFillerSelectedItem.CollectionRowId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [my answer to another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23834684/593090).  The problem is that the datagrid no longer has the focus after the user selects a row (or cell, actually); the cell that the user clicked *in* the datagrid does.  So you have to change the focus back to the datagrid to allow this.

Change:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>  
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding CmdTransUnitFillerRowDblClick}" />  
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

To:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>  
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding CmdTransUnitFillerRowDblClick}" />  
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding CmdTransUnitFillerRowClick}" />  
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

...and add:

```
private void ExecutecmdTransUnitFillerRowClick(object parameter)  
{
    if (DgTransUnitFillerSelectedItem != null)
        The_Name_Of_Your_DataGrid.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Untested, but couldn't he just listen to the DoubleClick event anyway and ignore e.Handled?

Comment: @TroelsLarsen The `DoubleClick` event on the `DataGrid` will never fire if the cell keeps the focus, so he has to either add another `DoubleClick` event on the cell or change the focus.

Comment: Ah.. I just saw that it was an InputBinding, not an event. :)

Comment: Thanks, makes sense after the explanation. Seems to be working for me

Comment: One thing that it might be worth noting is that `Focus`, besides just causing the `DataGrid` to be focused, also by default causes it to be brought into view by any `ScrollViewer` containing it, which might not be the desired behavior (at least it wasn't in my case, when I came across this answer); one way out of that is to attach the handler `(o, e) => e.Handled = true;` to the `RequestBringIntoView` event of the `DataGrid before focusing (and removing it again afterwards).

Comment: @klugerama, how can you do this using the MVVM format?

Answer (score 0):

On top of your existing InputBinding, you can use a Style to attach the InputBinding to each cell:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="local:MouseCommands.LeftDoubleClick" Value="ApplicationCommands.New" />
</Style>
```

This requires use of the MouseCommands class from [here](http://www.lanwin.de/2010/01/28/apply-command-inputbindings-on-styles/).

```
public static class MouseCommands
{
    private static void LeftDoubleClickChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var control = (Control)sender;

        if (args.NewValue != null && args.NewValue is ICommand)
        {
            var newBinding = new MouseBinding(args.NewValue as ICommand, new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftDoubleClick));
            control.InputBindings.Add(newBinding);
        }
        else
        {
            var oldBinding = control.InputBindings.Cast<InputBinding>().First(b => b.Command.Equals(args.OldValue));
            control.InputBindings.Remove(oldBinding);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftDoubleClickProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LeftDoubleClick",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(MouseCommands),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(LeftDoubleClickChanged));

    public static void SetLeftDoubleClick(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(LeftDoubleClickProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetLeftDoubleClick(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(LeftDoubleClickProperty);
    }
}
```

Though I think a cleaner way is to just handle the MouseDoubleClick event in the code-behind and manually raise the Command execution by calling your ViewModel directly, or calling .Execute() on the command.

Comment: I thought of going down the code-behind route but this was something setup by someone else and they didn't want to use code-behind so I have been attempting to keep that philosophy while attempting to fix this issue. I will give your solution a try.

Comment: This may work in some situations for me but with some interfaces we were using on the datagrid it was tossing errors like crazy. Saved the link to my favorites so I can reference in the future as needed