# WPF MVVM DataGrid DoubleClick not working when row is already selected

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, double-click

So I have a problem identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455461/issue-with-doubleclick-on-datagrid).
However, the solution to this appears to be Code-Behind (and is 4 years old) but I am using MVVM.  Time may have brought about a better solution to this.

Does anyone know of a way to have the double click work on a DataGridRow after it has been selected?

Here is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ContactsResult" 
          AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource DarkBlueBrush}"
          BorderThickness="1"
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
          GridLinesVisibility="None"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Results, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          >

          <DataGrid.InputBindings>
              <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                            Command="{Binding DetailsCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ContactsResult, Path=SelectedItem.ContactId}"
                            />
          </DataGrid.InputBindings>

          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="contactLastNameColumn" 
                                  Binding="{Binding Name_LastSufFirstMidSal}"
                                  ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCellPadding5}"                      Header="Contact Name" 
                                  Width="Auto" 
                                  />
              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="companyNameColumn"
                                  ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCellPadding5}"                      Header="Company Name"
                                  Width="Auto"
                                  />
              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CityColumn" 
                                  Binding="{Binding MailingAddress.City}" 
                                  ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCellPadding5}"                      Header="Mailing City"
                                  Width="Auto"
                                  />
              <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="StateColumn" 
                                  Binding="{Binding MailingAddress.StateOrProvince}"      ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCellPadding5}"                      Header="Mailing State" 
                                  Width="Auto"
                                  />
          </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

***EDIT***

ElementSytle

```
<Style x:Key="dgCellPadding5" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I am using your XAML, but am able to double click the selected row.  Perhaps my code is incomplete.  Can you post the undefined styles you are referencing?  And what version of .NET are you building against?

Comment: @Eric, post the style above as an edit.  I am using .NET 4.7.1.  If I have a row selected, and double click, nothing happens.  However, if i then deselect that row clearing the highlight, i can double click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to reach my goal, I decided to go a different route.

First I started with a Grid and used the attribute Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True".  In this grid I created a grid and an ItemsControl (with a grid in the datatemplate).  This gives me the appearance of a datagrid.

Second, in the itemscontrol I added InputBindings to each item to achieve the desired behaviour.  Here is what I came up with:

```
        <Border Grid.Row="2"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource BackgroundTitleBarBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Visibility="{Binding ResultGridVisible, Converter={local:BooleanToVisibilityValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=True}"
                    >

            <Grid Background="White" 
              Grid.Row="2"
              Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
              >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource SeperatorDarkBlueBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"
                    Margin="5 0"
                    Padding="3 5"
                    Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" Width="150"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="C" Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="D" Width="75"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="E" Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="F" Width="50"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundTitleBarBrush}"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Text="Contact Name"
                                   />
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundTitleBarBrush}"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="Company Name"
                                   />
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundTitleBarBrush}"
                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Text="Mailing"
                                   />
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundTitleBarBrush}"
                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Text="City"
                                   />
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundTitleBarBrush}"
                                   Grid.Column="3"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Text="State"
                                   />
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundTitleBarBrush}"
                                   Grid.Column="4"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Text="Other"
                                   />
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundTitleBarBrush}"
                                   Grid.Column="4"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Text="City"
                                   />
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundTitleBarBrush}"
                                   Grid.Column="5"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Text="State"
                                   />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" 
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                              MaxHeight="350"                              
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                              >
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Results}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border x:Name="Container" 
                                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SeperatorLightBlueBrush}" 
                                        BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"
                                        Margin="5 0"
                                        Padding="3 5"
                                        >
                                    <Border.InputBindings>
                                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                                                      Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DetailsCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:BasePage}}}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding ContactId}"
                                                      />
                                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightClick"
                                                      Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.NewWindowDetailsCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:BasePage}}}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding ContactId}"
                                                      />
                                    </Border.InputBindings>

                                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="D"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="E"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="F"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" 
                                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                                   Text="{Binding Name_LastSufFirstMidSal}"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   />
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" 
                                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                                   Text="{Binding Company}"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   />
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" 
                                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                                   Text="{Binding MailingAddress.City}"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   />
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" 
                                                   Grid.Column="3"
                                                   Text="{Binding MailingAddress.StateOrProvince}"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   />
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" 
                                                   Grid.Column="4"
                                                   Text="{Binding OtherAddress.City}"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   />
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" 
                                                   Grid.Column="5"
                                                   Text="{Binding OtherAddress.StateOrProvince}"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>

                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Container" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundLightBlueBrush}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>

                <Border Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="1" Visibility="{Binding NoRecordsFound, Converter={local:BooleanToCollapsedVisibilityValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=True, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <TextBlock Text="No Records Found"
                               Margin="5 0"
                               Padding="3 5"
                               />
                </Border>

            </Grid>

        </Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following sample, targeting .NET 4.7.1, fires double-click commands (regardless of selection status).  I've included the style you referenced, from above.  Is your code any different than this?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpfApp1="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <wpfApp1:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="dgCellPadding5" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="ContactsResult"
          AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          BorderThickness="1"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          GridLinesVisibility="None"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact, Mode=TwoWay}">

    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
                      Command="{Binding Command}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ContactsResult, Path=SelectedItem}" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCellPadding5}"
                            Binding="{Binding ContactName}"
                            Header="Contact Name"
                            Width="Auto" />
        <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCellPadding5}" Header="Company Name"
                            Binding="{Binding CompanyName}"
                            Width="Auto" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding City}" Header="Mailing City"
                            Width="Auto" ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCellPadding5}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding State}" Header="Mailing State"
                            Width="Auto" ElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCellPadding5}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class ViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public ContactInfo[] Contacts
        {
            get;
        } =
        {
            new ContactInfo
            {
                ContactName = "First",
                CompanyName = "Acme",
                City = "Somewhere",
                State = "CA"
            },
            new ContactInfo
            {
                ContactName = "Second",
                CompanyName = "Acme",
                City = "Somewhere",
                State = "CA"
            },
            new ContactInfo
            {
                ContactName = "Third",
                CompanyName = "Acme",
                City = "Somewhere",
                State = "CA"
            },
            new ContactInfo
            {
                ContactName = "Fourth",
                CompanyName = "Acme",
                City = "Somewhere",
                State = "CA"
            }
        };

        private ContactInfo _selectedContact;

        public ContactInfo SelectedContact
        {
            get => _selectedContact;
            set => SetProperty(ref _selectedContact, value);
        }

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get;
        } = new DelegateCommand<ContactInfo>(ci => Debug.WriteLine($"{ci.ContactName} {DateTime.Now}"));

        public ICommand OtherCommand
        {
            get;
        } = new DelegateCommand<string>(s => Debug.WriteLine($"{s} {DateTime.Now}"));
    }

    public class ContactInfo
    {
        public string ContactName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string CompanyName
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string City
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string State
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, mostly.  My parameter binding is Path=SelectedItem.ContactId (using EF for binding source).  And my IComannd is: SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await SearchAsync());  SearchAsync gets the results from the DB and returns the list of objects for EF.

Comment: And if you put a debugger breakpoint, or logging, in the double click command, you don't see it if the row is already selected?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.  When I place a BP in the View Model in the command that is ran by double clicking, I only see the content of the View Model.  Is there a way to place a BP in the View?

Comment: Does the breakpoint catch each time you double click, regardless of row selection?  Or does it only catch if the row is not selected?

Comment: Once the DataGrid populates. I can double click a row and hit the breakpoint.  This leaves the row highlighted.  If I double click again, the breakpoint is not hit.  If I single click to clear the highlight and then double click the row, the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Adding to that, I can also go right ahead and double click any other row and hit the breakpoint.  It seems that I cannot get the command to run on a row that currently is highlighted.  I have also (after datagrid population) just single clicked to highlight a row and tried to double click.  The breakpoint is not hit in that scenario either.

Comment: It appears to have to do with the cell.  I have a row highlighted, but if I double click the same cell used to highlight the row, nothing.  But if I double click a different cell in the highlighted row, the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Just the basic that come with making a new WPF with Visual studio.  This is my first WPF project so if have been following AngleSIx on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrW43fNmjaQVYF4zgsD0oL9Iv6u23PI6M

Answer (score 0):

I use Prism frame,this is my code :

```
   xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
 <controls:CustomDataGrid Grid.Row="2" 
                   SelectedItem="{Binding ModelItem}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ModelList}"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  Style="{StaticResource DataTriggerDataGridStyle}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding BtnNoticeViewCommand, IsAsync=True}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: This is my first WPF project.  Should I be using Prism?  Is there a benefit that just the default .NET WPF that Visual Studio provides?  I haven't seen the "InvokeCommandAction" before.

Comment: The benefit of default .NET WPF is simple and easy to know ,you can add the reference "Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity.dll",then you can  bind the event name to the command

Comment: This is my first time commenting here.哈哈